# Is always `setTimeout` and `setInterval` don't work with background pages?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is always `setTimeout` and `setInterval` don't work with background pages?

[The documentation for alarms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms) says:

> that those functions don't work with background pages that **are loaded
>   on demand**

But [the documentation for background scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts) says:

> Background scripts are loaded as soon as the extension **is loaded and
>   stay loaded until the extension is disabled or uninstalled**.

What does “that are loaded on demand” mean in the documentation for alarms?

Comment: setTimeout and setInterval should work in background pages. Please show us code where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Smile4ever Maybe this is one of the answers? https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1462126#c1

Comment: I believe so, thanks for linking the bug report.